# The sent Value from the main page to the post page shows up as word *Array*

Tags: php, html

Well , it's simple to explain

**Objectif** : I want to send the values of IDs taken from sql (addable by users) to Post Page form

**Current Bug** : I tried this code

in first page

```
    <?php
 session_start();

 $conn = mysqli_connect("localhost", "localhost", "localhost", "localhost");
// Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
}
$buyer      = $_SESSION['username'];
$sql_shells = "SELECT buytime,id,situation,buyer FROM shells WHERE situation = 'sold' AND buyer = '$buyer'  ";
$dt = new DateTime();
$dt->modify('+172799 seconds');
$hi = $dt->format('Y-m-d H:i:s');
$_SESSION["sup"] = [];

$result = $conn->query($sql_shells);
if ($result->num_rows > 0) {

while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
$_SESSION["sup"][] = $row['id'];
$_SESSION["sup"] = implode(',', $session['sup']);  // use this var

if ($hi <  $row['buytime']) {

         }else{

  echo " <form action='action.php' method='get'>
  Thanks for buying from our shop , if the item with id <input type='submit' value='" . $row['id'] ."' class='btn-link'/>  </form>";

  echo "<form action='action1.php' method='post'>
  is a bad tool , you can report by clicking on the following button <input  type='submit' value='Report Item' />
       </form>";
  }
  }
  }else {

  }

 ?>
```

and the form page which it's action1

```
<?php
session_start();
if (isset($_SESSION['username'])) {

server with default setting (user 'root' with no password) */
$link = mysqli_connect("localhost", "localhost", "localhost", 
"localhost");

if($link === false){
die("ERROR: Could not connect. " . mysqli_connect_error());
}
$trn_date = date("Y-m-d H:i:s");

$seller = $_SESSION['username']; 
$id = $_POST['whatever'];
$id = explode(',', $id); // You now have an array of IDs.
$sql = "INSERT INTO reports (reporter,stats,trn_date,itemid) VALUES 
('$seller','Opened','$trn_date','$id')";
if(mysqli_query($link, $sql)){
echo $id;
echo $seller;
} else{
echo "ERROR: Could not able to execute $sql. " . mysqli_error($link);
}

 } else
  {
  header("location:/quickshops/login.php");
 }
?>
```

Inserted Values are : Array **Literally the word Array** instead of the ids , and others are fine

Btw : already tested they seem fine when i did echo them in the first page , like Ids are real numbers

Comment: `print_r()` instead of `echo`

Comment: not the objectif , still gonna be the *Array* Word inserted

Comment: String representation of array is word __Array__. To get what you need - create your string as you need - with `implode` for example.

Comment: are we talking in the second page ? cause i got in the first page `$_SESSION["sup"] = implode(',', $session['sup']);  // use this var`

Comment: We are talking about the page which inserts `Array` to database.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You seem to be doing things such as the following (paraphrased);

```
$id = explode(...);
/* other code */
echo $id;
```

As said in the comments, this will print **Array** as that's the type that explode returns.
If your data is such as;

```
$_POST['whatever'] = "a,b,c,d"
```

Exploding this into id will produce;

```
$id = array(
    a
    b
    c
    d
)
```

Therefore, you need to loop these results to use them, or call by association (shown below respectively)

```
foreach ($id as $an_id)
{
    echo "ID = {$an_id} <br />";
}

echo "ID = {$id[0]} <br />";
echo "ID = {$id[1]} <br />";
echo "ID = {$id[2]} <br />";
echo "ID = {$id[3]} <br />";
```

Both of these will print;

```
ID = a
ID = b
ID = c
ID = d
```

Whereas, the below will give **Array** as the output;

```
print "{$id} <br />";
```

If you wanted to make this back into 1 string, you can do the following to return it back to it's normal state;

```
print implode(",", $id);
```

Giving you the following output;

```
a,b,c,d
```

Comment: It seems like i'm following the wrong method , but your answer is 100% true .